Is there a simple way to get SQL Workbench to only focus on one database?
Through my code I am having to write the database before the table name because otherwise I get an error as it's looking in the wrong database for the table I created. If you look at my code I am always writing sql_intro.emp_details rather than just emp_details. Is there a simpler way to do this?
This is my code:
create database sql_intro;
show databases;
create table sql_intro.emp_details (Name varchar(25), Age int, Sex char(1),
doj date, City varchar(15), Salary float);
describe sql_intro.emp_details;
insert into sql_intro.emp_details
values("Jimmy",35,"M","2005-05-30","Chicago",70000),
("Shane",30,"M","1999-06-25","Seattle",55000),
("Marry",28,"F","2009-03-10","Boston",62000),
("Dwayne",37,"M","2011-07-12","Austin",57000),
("Sara",32,"F","2017-10-27","New York",72000),
("Ammy",35,"F","2014-12-20","Seattle",80000);
Select * from sql_intro.emp_details;


use sql_intro;

will switch your database
